# How does Ubuntu handle OS transfers?

Tags: hardware

I have two systems. One of them is running Ubuntu 14.04. The other has everything needed to run, except a bootable drive. The two systems have nothing in common. The running system has old hardware. The other system has shiny new and modern hardware, several orders of magnitude faster than the running system. If I just move the drive with Ubuntu on it to the other system, will Ubuntu adapt without problems? Will I need to install a massive batch of hardware drivers?

Comment: It probably will. Lots of people use Live USBs with a permanent, portable install of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

> will Ubuntu adapt without problems?

In general: yes.  The normal device drivers get recreated on every boot so those will switch to the new hardware.

- As stated in comments: pay attention to the boot process. If one is old skool non-(u)efi and the other is... you need to boot the new system with the method the old one used.
- The one thing you always should do is remove all 3rd party drivers. You can run into problems going from a nVidia to an AMD GPU or from a AMD to a nVidia GPU. Same for your NIC: 3rd party driver, delete it before switching. Those blobs are all static so will mess up your new system.

  In general you can fix that too though with a "reconfigure" from commandline.

I know you are going from old to new but in case you would go from new to old:

- Ubuntu has for every release a hardware stack. An LTS will update the hardware stack to the newest normal release stack (so 1n.04.2 has 1n.10's stack, 1n.04.3 has 1(n+1).04's =2 , 1n.04.4 had 1(n+1).10's stack for n=4 or n=6). Those hardware stacks also remove older hardware that is deemed obsolete. If you are unlucky your hardware is far too old to run an newer version.

Comment: The boot mode could also be relevant (Legacy BIOS or modern UEFI). Ubuntu can be installed in both modes, but it must boot in the mode it got installed.

Comment: My new motherboard is UEFI only, and the old one is BIOS only as you might have guessed. Do I need to freshly reinstall Ubuntu to make it work on the new motherboard? It would be problematic, but I think I'll manage.